# Forecast/Prediction based on older Data

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, tensorflow, forecasting

I have created a platform with live updates and comparisons of CoVid-19 cases around the world.

https://coronavirus-meter.com/

I have statistics (cases/recovered/deaths) for all the countries from 22 Jan to today and i am trying to forecast the next days statistics.

Ex. In a country based on its cases/recovered/deaths how can i calculate what is going to happen in the next 3 days?

Maths is not my strong point but what I have tried is:

1. Averaging the last X days but its not the quality solution i want here.
2. Created a NN with TensorFlow JS and trained a model with a country statistics but it just give me a linear prediction which again does not seem to fit my needs (i am really newbie to TensorFlow so i am not sure i am doing the correct things anyway)

If anyone could give me a fast and fairly accurate solution for a prediction/forecast would be much appreciated. Maybe its a fair easy solution but again Maths is not my strong skill.

Site is written is HTML,JS so i will do any implementation with JS/jQuery. Well, give me a function like concept or a road to take and i will try implementing myself. I am stuck in equations in wikipedia thta i cannot even read properly!

PS. As its a non-profit site about CoVid-19 cases, i have it public on github so anyone may check it out!  https://github.com/agaktr/coronavirus-meter

Answer (score 0):

I've build a simple automated job which runs every day. It gathers data from the John Hopkins University and estimates ARIMA-type time-series models for each country-province combination for which data is available and at least 30 cases haven been confirmed. For each of these units, I forecast the contagion dynamics (confirmed cases to be precise) for the forthcoming 7 days.

URL: https://github.com/atecon/covid_19_forecast/

Maybe that gives you an idea in which direction to go with your project.